# Why pip version isn't 9 when installing?

Tags: python, pip

I always install **pip** with **python** in every server I use, but no matter what platform I have, it always installs version 8, then when installing a package, it suggests upgrade:

> You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Why is **pip v9.0.1** not installed by default?

Comment: How are you installing pip?

Comment: @Chris in ubuntu it's `sudo apt install pip3`, and the pip coming in Python3 windows installer has the same problem.

Comment: `pip` is not tied to (C)Python release schedule, and packers of Python binaries don't have to include `pip` at all - if they're including it, they tend to choose a version they used for their test builds and until something significantly changes they don't really upgrade it. There is little reason to build a new `pip` package every time a new version comes up when `pip` is perfectly capable of keeping itself up to date.

Comment: It depends on your installed packages, the package manager you use and lots of other stuff. Maybe it's just incompatible with another package you use and the dependency resolver only found pip 8 matching the other installed packages. It's impossible to answer this question without knowing your system, your installed packages, the package manager and how you installed your programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because an OS ships with pre-determined list of repositories and if a software is updated the authors have to update their software in that repository for you to have an up-to-date version. `pip` is capable of updating itself, so you notice the discrepancy between the current version and the version provided in your repositories.

Further reading [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210394).

Example:
If you are running Ubuntu xenial (16.04LTS) the version of pip when that Ubuntu version was tested with was `8.1.1-2: all`. If you would be running Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) and do `sudo apt install pip` you'd get `9.0.1-2: all`.

See [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pip) for more details on `python-pip` version in various Ubuntu repositories.